# How to use 2 form tag in same page in Yii

Tags: php, yii, yii2, yii2-advanced-app

In frontend  of Yii , 
   I have 2 form    :
            1 Login Form
            2 Signup 
   my signup form is working , but when login is not working  , 
     i found a error
     Call to a member function formName() on null

**//Form Code**

```
<!-------signup---------->
<h1>Signup  Form</h1>
<?php $form = ActiveForm::begin(['id' => 'form-signup', 'action' => Url::to(['site/signup'])]); ?>
    <?= $form->field($modelSignup, 'username')->textInput(['autofocus' => true]) ?>
    <?= $form->field($modelSignup, 'email') ?>
    <?= $form->field($modelSignup, 'password')->passwordInput() ?>
    <?= Html::submitButton('Signup', ['class' => 'btn btn-primary', 'name' => 'signup-button']) ?>
<?php ActiveForm::end(); ?>
<!-------// signup---------->

<!-------login---------->
<h1>Login  Form</h1>
<?php $form = ActiveForm::begin(['id' => 'form-login', 'action' => Url::to(['site/login'])]); ?>
    <?= $form->field($modelLogin, 'username')->textInput(['autofocus' => true]) ?>
    <?= $form->field($modelLogin, 'email') ?>
    <?= $form->field($modelLogin, 'password')->passwordInput() ?>
    <?= Html::submitButton('Login', ['class' => 'btn btn-primary', 'name' => 'login-button']) ?>
<?php ActiveForm::end(); ?>
<!-------//login---------->
```

Comment: pls show your from code too!

Comment: have you passed `$modelLogin` from controller? pls show your controller login action too.

Comment: public function actionIndex()
    {
  
  if(isset($_REQUEST['signup']))
  {
   $modelSignup = new SignupForm();
        return $this->render('index',[
   'modelSignup' => $modelSignup,
  ]);
  }
  else{
   $modelLogin = new LoginForm();
        return $this->render('index',[
   'modelLogin' => $modelLogin,
  ]);
  }
    }

Comment: hi @ErSahajArora, actually what is your main issue.. share the code

Comment: @SherinJose ; Hello Sherin , My issue is how can i use multiple forms on same page ,    I have to use form on index page of frontend , but one form is working but during use another form its give an error    : Call to a member function formName() on null    ,,, so my ques is this how to use multiple form in php & Yii2

Comment: The issue maybe in your controller.. anyway by guessing that  i will post an answer

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

Controller:

```
public function actionIndex() { 
       $modelSignup = new SignupForm(); 
       $modelLogin = new LoginForm();      
       return $this->render('index',[ 'modelSignup' => $modelSignup,'modelLogin' => $modelLogin ]);        
 }
```

Also remove this check from your code:

```
if(isset($modelLogin)
```

Comment: <?php if(isset($modelLogin)) { ?> ............. <?php } ?>
by that code login  form not display       , because   that code means when we click on login that time will show form

Comment: In index.php i have 2 forms thats code alery i put in query

Comment: Any one Help please  ??

Comment: @ErSahajArora still same issue?

Answer (score 0):

In your view file you are using two models, one for `signup` and the other for `login`. But from your comment I had note that you are passing only one model at a time it may be the first one or the second one. So you should replace your `actionIndex()` with the following code:

```
public function actionIndex() {
    $modelSignup    = new SignupForm();
    $modelLogin     = new LoginForm();
    if(isset($_POST['SignupForm'])) {
        //code for signup process
    }

    if(isset($_POST['LoginForm'])) {
        //code for login process
    }

    return $this->render('index', [ 'modelSignup' => $modelSignup, 'modelLogin' => $modelLogin ]); 
}
```

This will help you.